# Probability of events conditioned on one of the events not occuring

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I have a random variable $X \in \{1,2,3\}$ with pmf,

$$
p(x) = [ p_1, \ p_2, \ p_3]
$$

such that $p_1 +p_2 +p_3 =1$.

I would like to find the probability $P(X=x | x \ne2)$

That is,

$$
P(X=x |x \ne 2) = \frac{P(X=x,x\ne2)}{P(x\ne2)}
$$

Now, $P(x\ne2) = P(x=1,x=3) =1-p_2$

But I am having difficulty calculating $P(X=x,x\ne2)$.

I believe some how that $p_2$ is distributed to the events $x=1$ and $x=3$. But not sure how it is distributed.

I wrote the conditional probability matrix for events $x\ne2$ and $x=2$

$$
\begin{array}{l|ll}
P(X|X\ne 2) &1 &2 &3\\ \hline
1 &? &0 &?\\
0 &0 &1 &0
\end{array}
$$

Since $P(X|X=2) = [0,\  1,\ 0]$

I have read that when events such as $X$ are partitions of the sample space that it must be $\sum_x P(X=x|x\ne2) =1$. So row's must sum to one in the conditional probability matrix.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try to draw a venn diagram? Things become much more clear. When computing the joint probability of $(X=x,X\neq x2)$ notice that the first event is a subset of the second, so the intersection is just $(X=x)$. Now for the conditional probability you need to divide that by $1-p_2$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes things much more clear. I sometimes find it difficult to keep track of how everything is when occuring together. I knew it had to be something simple I wasn't thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle \small P(X=x |x \ne 2) = \frac{P \big((X=x) \cap (x \ne 2)\big)}{P(x\ne2)}$

$\small P(x \ne 2) = 1 - p_2 = p_1 + p_3$

$\small P ((X=1) \cap (x \ne 2)) = P(X = 1) = p_1$

$\small P ((X=3) \cap (x \ne 2)) = P(X = 3) = p_3$

So,

$\displaystyle \small P(X=1 |x \ne 2) = \frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_3}$

$\displaystyle \small P(X=3 |x \ne 2) = \frac{p_3}{p_1 + p_3}$